# Posting metric to google analytics from perl script

Tags: perl, google-analytics

I need to generate a google analytic event from my perl cron job.

Based on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide
POST to www.google-analytics.com/collect will accept the metrics.

I tried posting metric using following code, but I am not seeing them in google analytics realtime page.

```
use LWP::UserAgent; 
$ua=LWP::UserAgent->new; 
$ua->default_header("Content-type" => "application/x-rm-urlencoded"); 
my $response = $ua->post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", 
"v" => 1, 
"tid" => "UA-XXXXXXXX-Y", 
"cid" => 125, 
"t" => "pageview", 
"dh" => "Cron", 
"dp" => "Cron.php", 
"dt" => "CronTitle"); 
print $response->status_line;'
```

Response is "200 OK", but I am not seeing the data in google analytics webpage.

Comment: Shouldn't the `"dh"` parameter include your host address? *e.g.*   `&dh=yourhostname.com ` ?

Comment: Did you look in the Realtime view ? Data will not show up instantaneously in the standard reports.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes. I am tracking realtime view, but I am not seeing pageview data for Cron.php page.

Comment: @Htaras re: your comment on my deleted "answer" (which I deleted since I had meant to post it as a comment): if you have tried adding your hostname to `dh`, but are still not seeing this metric in GA, are you able to capture or log the responses you get? I assume you mean `200 OK` above, but do any of the other issues mentioned in the [developper's guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) apply?  For example is there a proxy server in the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to post analytics from my php scripts, but could not post analytics from perl script.

I solved my problem as follows. 
Created an utility php script and called that php script from my perl script. Then it worked.

```
<?php 
    $ec = $_GET['ec'];
    $ea = $_GET['ea'];
    $el = $_GET['el'];
    $ev = $_GET['ev'];

    // Send event tracking as well.
    $url = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
    $event_data = array(
            'v' => '1', 
            'tid' => 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 
            'cid' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
            't' => 'event', 
            'ec' => $ec,
            'ea' => $ea,
            'el' => $el,
            'ev' => $ev);
    $event_options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($event_data),
            ),
        );
    $event_context  = stream_context_create($event_options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $event_context);

    echo "XXX";
?>
```